# Soft question about the ideal number of exercises to do when self studying

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, education

This is a soft question for which there is no objective right answer. I am wondering about how many exercise questions at the end of a chapter in a pure math upper division undergraduate to graduate level book one "should" do in order to sufficiently understand the material, and how can I choose the most "appropriate" set of questions (i.e. one that would maximize my learning without being repetitive exercises)? Of course, there is no "should" in the objective sense, hence the quotation mark. The way to go about this can be as follows:

1. Find some publicly available university course website about the same subject you are studying, and if it has a list of weekly homework assignments, do them, and possibly check the answer online.
2. If the book has solutions for some select problems at the end of a book, do them
3. avoid doing hundreds of mechanical rote calculation problems

However, I am wondering how my answer would be answered if 1 and 2 are not available. Even for 2, the select problems may consist of many questions that question the reader similar things. In general, how do professors choose their homework assignments to give to students, i.e. if you are a pure math professor, what makes you determine that certain questions would be 'good' for your students and certain others would be not quite necessary? I understand that this last question depends on professors, but what principles do math professors use in general to pick exercises?

Comment: The ideal number of exercises in ring theory is the number of exercises concerning ideals. Sorry, I coudn't resist. To be more serious, I think it is not the question "how many" exercises you do, but "how" you are doing these. For example, there are hundreds of exercises on cyclic groups, but often already the first ten of them will show you whether you understood cyclic groups or not yet.

Comment: "if you are a pure math professor, what makes you determine that certain questions would be 'good' for your students and certain others would be not quite necessary?" Actually, this depends on opinions. For me, say, for cyclic groups, my first test question would be - can you determine without effort whether or not the group $GL_n(\Bbb C)$, known from matrices and linear algebra,  is cyclic?

Comment: Options 1. and 2. aside, if the only other option left is "*3. doing hundreds of mechanical rote calculation problems*" then, sorry, but you are reading the wrong book.

Comment: Among many factors, I think it also depends on the choice of the textbook and the subject matter. For example, if you are reading a first year Calculus textbook, then there is no point of doing 15 exercises on u-substitution (if you do 4 sufficiently different examples, it is probably enough, at least for the first pass). If you are reading Serre's _Linear Representation of Finite Groups_, then each exercise in that book shows you something novel, and so there it makes sense to do many more exercises from each section.

Comment: "The reader is not required to do any of the exercises unless he cannot do them." Carl Linderholm, Mathematics Made Difficult.